# Chrome Tab Freezing and SetTimeout/Web Workers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

Chrome 79 was just released with the [new tab freezing feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/444481/how-chromes-tab-freezing-will-save-cpu-and-battery/) turned on by default. Does anyone know of a way to get around this when working with setTimeouts (or even web workers) in JavaScript?

We have some code running to check for client activity in order to facilitate a more graceful timeout/logout after a set amount of time. Unfortunately, neither of these work when the tab is in a 'frozen' state.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's the point of freezing the tab: to prevent scripts from running. About your graceful logout: on the client side, run a setInterval to check if you are still logged in, or check it when you connect to your backend. On server side: logout the user if not heard from in a set amount of time. The users computer could be turned off, lost network, or have a frozen tab.

Comment: @some Can't run a setInterval when the the tab is frozen. We're already timing users out from the server side; our client-side code is to ensure that the user won't lose unsaved changes prior to that happening.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Of course neither setTimeout or setInterval will run when the tab is frozen since that is the point of freezing the tab. But why call setTimeout and then in the setTimeout-handler call setTimeout again? Anyway, have you seen the [page lifecycle events](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) ?

Comment: For example "When the page changes from active to passive, it's a good time to persist unsaved application state."

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into the lifecycle events, but I'm not sure they'll solve my problem. When a user's page become unfrozen, they may have already been logged out by the server. If that's occurred, the user's next interaction with the server will fail and they'll be rerouted to a log in page. And app state I've saved therefore is sort of useless. Perhaps I'll notify the user prior to the tab being frozen - this is when they could choose to keep their tab, and therefore their session, active.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [age lifecycle api](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api) I created this class:

```js
const pageLifecycle = new class PageLifecycle extends EventTarget {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = this.getState();
    const fn = () => this.stateChange(this.getState()),
      opt = { capture: true },
      events = {
        pageshow: fn,
        focus: fn,
        blur: fn,
        visibilitychange: fn,
        resume: fn,
        freeze: () => this.stateChange("frozen"),
        pagehide: event => this.stateChange(event.persisted ? "frozen" : "terminated")
      };
    for (const [event, fn] of Object.entries(events)) window.addEventListener(event, fn, opt);
  }
  getState() {
    return document.visibilityState === "hidden" ? "hidden" : document.hasFocus() ? "active" : "passive";
  }
  stateChange(nextState) {
    if (nextState === this.state) return;
    const prevState = this.state;
    this.state = nextState;
    this.dispatchEvent(Object.assign(new Event("stateChange"), { prevState, state: this.state }));
  }
};

//--------
pageLifecycle.addEventListener("stateChange", event => console.log(`State change: ${event.prevState} >>> ${event.state}`));
```

You can add an event listener to it (event:`stateChange`), and you get one of `["active", "passive", "hidden", "frozen", "terminated"]` in `event.state`. Check for `passive` and save your data. You can check `event.prevState` to get the previous state to determinate if you should force a check to the backend to see if the user is still loggen in.